# How do I query a table by list of values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

```
Person
-----------
id
name
doctor_id

Doctor
-----------
id
name

Person_Doctor
-------------
id
person_id
doctor_id
```

The idea is that a person can have more than one doctor, and a doctor can have more than one patient (person).

What I want to do is get all of a person's doctors by id. Here's my prelim strategy:

```
SELECT * FROM Person_Doctor WHERE person_id=:id
```

and then map each `Person_Doctor` to the corresponding doctor by `doctor_id`. The thing with this approach is that I'll have to query the DB for each Person_Doctor object, seems expensive. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  Do yo know how to use SQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select p.name as patient, d.name as doctor
From person as p inner join person_doctor as pd on pd.person_id = id
                 inner join doctor as d on pd.doctor_id = d.id
where p.id = SomeID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly basic `JOIN`, which is a fundamental element of relational databases. I'd recommend once you've finished this assignment, studying up and perhaps taking a college level course in databases. The problems you'll encounter while working in SQL will all be harder than this one.

```
SELECT d.name as 'doctor name' 
FROM doctor d
    INNER JOIN person_doctor pd on d.doctor_id = pd.doctor_id
    INNER JOIN person ON p p.person_id = pd.person_id
WHERE p.person_id = @id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id
FROM person p 
        join person_doctor pd 
            on p.id = pd.person_id 
        join doctor d 
            on pd.doctor_id = d.id
WHERE p.doctor_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Please consider formatting your code answers so their are easier to read.